# Problems importing a python module in Maya and it being recognized

Tags: python, import, module, maya

Still learning certain things about Python...  I am having issues recognizing my Python script in my scripts dir.  First, I checked to see that my path is set correctly:

```
import sys
for pythonPath in sys.path:
    print pythonPath
```

And `C:/Users/..../Documents/maya/2014-x64/scripts` is listed, which is where I am placing `swap.py`

In Maya's script editor I am typing the following:

```
import swap
reload(swap)
swap.printSomething()
```

I get:

## Error: AttributeError: file  line 3: 'module' object has no attribute 'printSomething' #

If I take the same code and throw it into a package...

C:/Users/..../Documents/maya/2014-x64/scripts/swapPackage/swap.py

And then call this, it works...

```
import swapPackage.swap as swap
reload(swap)
swap.printSomething()
```

Why?  I am totally confused.  Mel scripts even run fine from this location as well.  I just can't get a simple python script to import and run.

Also something I noticed.  Even though I can get this script to run in a package, the package name must be totally different than the module name.  I can't have a package named this:

```
C:/Users/..../Documents/maya/2014-x64/scripts/swap/swap.py
```

but I can have one where the package name is different:

```
C:/Users/..../Documents/maya/2014-x64/scripts/swapPackage/swap.py
```

Comment: Ok folks, I was able to solve this by executing a print of my __file__, only to find out that it was sourcing a totally different version someone copied elsewhere.  ARGH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok folks, I was able to solve this by executing a print of my **file**, only to find out that it was sourcing a totally different version someone copied elsewhere.  ARGH.  This solves both issues, and makes sense why changing the package name from the module worked.

```
import swap
    reload(swap)
    print swap.__file__
```